# template expressions and visual studio 2005 c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, templates, visual-c++-2005

I'd like to build the olb3d library with my visual studio 2005 compiler but this failes due to template errors.

To be more specific, the following expression seem to be a problem:

```
void function(T u[Lattice<T>::d])
```

On the website of the project is stated that prpably my compiler is not capable of such complicated template expressions - one should use the gcc 3.4.1.

My question is now if there is a way to upgrade my vs c++ compiler so it can handle template expressions on the level as the gcc 3.4.1? Maybe it helps if I get a newer version of visual studio?

Cheers 
C.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code?  Perhaps a complete snippet that should compile but doesn't?

Comment: The `Lattice<T>::d` part seems to be completely unnecessary, because arrays decay into pointers and the value between `[]` is just ignored. (May-be you are not posting a real example.)

Comment: Post a more meaningful description of the problem. From what you posted so far there's no reason to believe that *any* compiler will be able to handle your code (quite the opposite, actually).

Comment: @AndreyT: GCC and Comeau seem to do fine with it. Perhaps it counts as non-deducible context and VC++ is right too?

Comment: @UncleBens A nondeducible context is explicitly allowed to contain both nondeduced and deduced parameters (the standard gives a function type as an example, but array types are just as eligible). So the example should still compile. In fact, before deduction is even done, `T u[...]` is transformed to `T*`, so the nondeduced context won't even show up during deduction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler says that it cannot deduce the template type. You can always help it out by specifying the type itself in your code.

```
foo<int>(some_int_array);
```

However, the part between `[]` that is tripping it up is completely meaningless. Arrays decay into pointers and the value is ignored in the first place. You can just comment out that part if this is a real example.

If you take the array by reference, VC++2005 doesn't appear to have any problem with it either:

```
template <class T>
void function(T (&arr)[Lattice<T>::n]);
```

(Is it possible that the case that doesn't compile is just so meaningless that no-one ever bothered to check if things like that work?)

Comment: You are absolutely right. They should have written just func(T* u) and it would have worked... but the source of olb3d is full of this odd template statements... I guess I will give up from trying to compile it within the windows environment.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a newer version of Visual Studio. 2005 is quite old and not very conformant. You can always test the new one first by downloading [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).

Comment: I tried VS 2010 but the compiler errors are still there... the template code of olb3d seems to be odd...